# Is mapping a 'GET' request to 'controller#destroy' in Rails routes.rb dangerous/bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, routes, crud, rails-routing

I'm wondering what the convention is regarding the use of GET requests mapped to 'destroy' actions in Rails. I was checking out the [RailsCast on authentication](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) and Ryan chose to map a GET request to the sessions#destroy action so that he could just link to it using a simple anchor tag, rather than a form_for/button_to helper to generate a button which contains the _method: delete attribute:

```
Auth::Application.routes.draw do  
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"  
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"  

  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"  
  root :to => "users#new"  
  resources :users  
  resources :sessions  
end
```

I was under the impression that this is not how it is supposed to be done, but Ryan Bates is one of the creators of Rails so I'm wondering if this is really as big of a deal as I've been made to believe.

Are there any serious downsides to this kind of routing implementation or is it primarily a stylistic convention meant to promote clarity?

Comment: You don't have to use a `form_for` or `button_to` to create a DELETE request; you can use the `method: :delete` option with `link_to`.

Comment: true enough but the link_to helper will generate a link which uses javascript to create a form with a hidden field storing the 'delete' method; not very unobtrusive if youre trying to make sure your page will work without javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're violating the [spec for HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) if you use GET for destroy actions:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe". This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested. (9.1.1)